How can I diagnose why my iPhone cell service would be unpredictably up and down?
I’ve got ATT and called them and confirmed my account is paid up and the cell phone towers are fine. My phone normally works completely fine. Today there have been weird periods of losing internet data for periods of time. I do not know if it’s something about the specific part of the city I’m in, where the range of the towers would be blocked by nearby buildings, or just a random fluke in their towers, or my phone having some kind of quirk, getting confused about recognizing the signal / network. But it’s been unpredictable and I want to know how to actually methodically investigate all possibilities to identify the cause.

The carrier’s customer service rep can’t confirm something is working without sending a tech to the cell site to do diagnostics. I wouldn’t put any stock in what they say. You need to test to see if WiFi Internet is stable, if you get the same symptoms in a different area of a friend/relative has the same carrier and  the same problem in the same area.

If it happens also in other places, the SIM card may be broken. You should get a replacement from ATT.
